# Mahout spark-shell Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, mahout

I'm just initiating in Mahout and Spark and trying to run the example from mahout's page on this link:

[Playing with Mahout's Spark Shell](https://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/play-with-shell.html)

Everything appears to start but when I try to run the follow command, it returns the error below:

```
val y = drmData.collect(::, 4)
```

> [Stage 0:>                                                          (0
>   + 0) / 2] 15/09/26 18:38:09 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that
>   workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Can anyone help me with this!

My environment is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
export MAHOUT_HOME=/home/celso/Downloads/mahout/mahout
export SPARK_HOME=/home/celso/Downloads/spark-1.4.1
export MASTER=spark://celso-VirtualBox:7077
```

I tried to set MAHOUT_LOCAL to true too.

Comment: How did you start your shell?

Comment: I did follow the tutorial on the link, first started spark with sbin/start-all.sh on SPARK_HOME, then on mahout's home i ran sbin/mahout spark-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made the example work.

I just setted the environment variable `MASTER` to `local`:

```
export MASTER=local
```

intead of

```
export MASTER=spark://hadoopvm:7077
```

The example worked!

Answer (score 0):

The Mahout 0.11.x Spark Shell is not yet compatible with Spark 1.4.1.

The most recent release, Mahout 0.11.0, requires Spark 1.3.x.

Mahout 0.10.2 is compatible with Spark 1.2.x and earlier.

Comment: I setuped my environment again with mahout-0.11 and spark 1.3.1 and have no success. Any other hint?

Comment: You changed your SPARK_HOME variable to point to your Spark 1.3.1 install, correct?  What error are you getting now? btw.. I think you meant MAHOUT_LOCAL rather than SPARK_LOCAL... You can unset that.

Comment: I corrected the post, the variable name is MAHOUT_LOCAL. The error I got is the same on my first post, Initial job has not accepted any resources. Could it be something related on available memory on linux? The environment is running under an Ubuntu, with 2Gb of RAM.